# Independence Day ship vs X-Files ship

Tags: spaceship, the-x-files, independence-day

I just rewatched the X-Files movie (the first one).  Is the spaceship at the end the same model as the one from Independence Day?  Both are made by Fox Pictures (I think), and Mulder, um, relieves himself on an Independence Day poster early in the movie.  That got me thinking that maybe there are other links between the movies, especially the spaceship.

Did Fox Pictures re-use the model?  Were they inspired by it at least?

I also remember previous spaceships in X-files episodes looking either like stereotypical flying saucers or as triangular ships, not large, flattish round ones like the one in Independence Day, and the one at the end of the X-Files is large, flattish, and round like the one in Independence Day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope. The model in Fight the Future appears to be a wholly original creation for the film.

The actual 'screen-used' prop was [auctioned](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://bid.profilesinhistory.com/HERO-SCREEN-USED-ILLUMINATING-ALIEN-SPACECRAFT-FILMING-MINIATURE-FROM-THE-X-FILES-FEATURE-FILM_i13427440) a few years back and although the main link is now dead, the high quality image they posted is still live.

[image]

By comparison, you can see a model made from the [original casting moulds](http://www.therpf.com/showthread.php?t=93015) below. Even if you ignore the size differential, a quick glance should show you that the main details are not the same, aside from the fact that they're both grey disks

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yep, different ship models.  I was crew chief at VIFX and lead a small crew making the X-Files model. I made the center section out of ema and plastruct tubing and acid etch brass.  https://www.michaelpossert.com/

Comment: While interesting and intriguing, the web site link does not seem to lead to information directly related to this question. Do you have a link to something actually relevant, or should the link simply be elided? See also the [promotion policy.](/help/promotion)